# DateTime in Javascript with T and Z

Tags: javascript, html

What are the letter T and Z inside a datetime ?
I am trying to understand the format so I can properly convert this string to a datetime object in EST timezone using JavaScript

```
DateUtc: "2017-05-01T14:00:00Z"
```

Comment: `javascript` != `java`. Which is it?

Comment: See [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) on Wikipedia. [`T`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations) is a letter(!) separating the date part from the time part. [`Z`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#UTC) is a letter(!) indicating that the time zone is `UTC`.

Comment: @Andreas—UTC isn't a timezone, it's a standard that uses offset +0000. ;-)

Comment: can you help on how to convert it to datetime object ?

Comment: @RobG Saying that `Z` indicates that the time zone is `UTC`, is shorthand for saying that the time zone *of the date/time value given in the string* is *at offset zero from* `UTC`, i.e. is the same as time zone `UTC+00:00`, aka is the same as `UTC`.